# Get Element where TypeElement is defined in?

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

I have the following class:

```
public class Start extends PlacePresenter {

    @NameToken("startPage")
    public interface MyProxy extends ProxyPlace {
    }
}
```

In an annotation processor I got the Element annotated with @NameToken which is MyProxy.

```
@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
        RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

  for (Element annotatedElement : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(NameToken.class)) {

    TypeElement typeElement = (TypeElement) annotatedElement;
    // typeElement is MyProxy
  }
}
```

**How do I get the Element of the class MyProxy is defined in, i.e., `Start`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The containing class will be represented by the `Element` returned by calling `annotatedElement.getEnclosingElement()`:

```
@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    for (Element annotatedElement : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(NameToken.class)) {
        System.out.println(annotatedElement.getEnclosingElement()); // prints "Start"
    }
    return true;
}
```